# Fallback font family used on a moved WordPress site

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, fonts

I'm moving my WordPress site to another server. I've copied the WP installation and the database successfully and the site is fully operational and looks otherwise OK, but the font I'm using on the header (that's visible on all pages) is not the one set in the CSS. Instead, it uses the `sans-serif` fallback font family.

The weird thing is, this wrong font family is only used on the main page. When I open any other page on the site, the font changes back to the right one. What could cause this?

The font family is declared like this in the CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'NobileRegular';
    src: url('skins/fonts/nobile/nobile-webfont.eot');
    src: url('skins/fonts/nobile/nobile-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('skins/fonts/nobile/nobile-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('skins/fonts/nobile/nobile-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('skins/fonts/nobile/nobile-webfont.svg#NobileRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And the font is applied like this:

```
body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'NobileRegular', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    // other stuff here
}
```

If I check the style info using Chrome's element inspection, the `font-family` is correct - It's just that the `sans-serif` fallback is used instead of the `NobileRegular`, and this happens only on the main page. The exact same `style.css` is loaded for all the pages as it's included in the `header.php` of the theme.

The exact same WordPress installation that's still running on the old server works just fine, with the correct font shown on each page.

What could cause this? Could it be some kind of caching issue?

Comment: refresh your page using combination key ctrl+f5;

Comment: It doesn't help. The font's wrong on other devices as well.

Comment: If you look at the home page via dev tools what CSS is being applied, can you see anything overwriting it?

Comment: can you correctly download the font file at the URL specified in the css? possible reasons could be that you might have moved them to wrong directories, or your htaccess could be preventing access to resources of such extensions.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you set up the startpage in worpress to another one instead of your default homepage?
Any URL to test?